# "Во внутрь"

Tags: грамотная-речь

На транспорте порой пишут "двери открываются ВО ВНУТРЬ". Разве это правильно? Разве не "открываются внутрь"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если "во внутрь" - то неправильно. Надо слитно: "вовнутрь". Это разговорный вариант к внутрь. И надо сказать, весьма распространенный, возможно будет признан нормативным без ограничений.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно, конечно, внутрь,  но именно в таком сочетании неправильное **вовнутрь** за 30-40 лет  стало очень привычным. Когда появились первые югославские автобусы, на их желтых дверях было написано именно так. В то время была студенткой, и преподаватели обращали внимание на грубую ошибку. И сегодня словари дают помету разговорное (то есть в официальной речи, в письменной речи - только **внутрь**), а некоторые и с пометой сниженное, разговорное.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно согласна с вторым ответом (с той лишь разницей,что мы считали жёлтые "Икарусы" не югославскими, а венгерскими автобусами). А это дикое "вовнутрь" до сих пор слух режет.

Answer (score 1):

В современной речи наречие/предлог ВОВНУТРЬ считается разговорным вариантом наречия/предлога ВНУТРЬ, но исторически это разные выражения.

Исходными формами являются словосочетания  В  НУТРЕ/НУТРИ (П.п., где, значение места) и ВО НУТРЬ (В.п., куда, значение направленности).  Затем происходит слияние ВНУТРИ  для первой формы, а вторая начинает применяться как ВО (В)НУТРЬ (в таком виде она зафиксирована у Даля). А затем  разница в значениях перестает ощущаться, происходит упрощение форм.

Но это до тех пор, пока надпись не появляется в автобусе. Здесь генетическая память слова как бы восстанавливается, будоража умы носителей русского языка (грубая ошибка, дикое выражение, режет слух). И всё-таки в транспортной лексике слово смотрится вполне приемлемо, подчеркивая значение направленности.

Но, во избежание проявления негативных эмоций, хорошо бы для  слова ВОВНУТРЬ иметь две пометки (просторечно-разговорное и профессиональное).

Answer (score 1):

Икарусы - не югославские, а венгерские автобусы. На их дверях было написано: "Осторожно, вовнутрь открывается!" Где-то году в 80-м я написал письмо в Будапешт на завод Икарус, написал по-русски в надежде, что переводчика там найдут легко. В нём поблагодарил за вместительные автобусы, облегчившие транспортную проблему, и заметил, что правильно будет: "Осторожно, открывается внутрь!" Можете себе представить, через некоторое время на улицах города появились новые автобусы с моим текстом.