# Внутрь и вовнутрь

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему на дверях автобуса написано:открывается **вовнутрь**, а не **внутрь**?И еще, **запасный выход*, но** запасной игрок**

Answer (score 1):

Наречие "вовнутрь" обсуждалось здесь:  ["Во внутрь"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4352/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8C-)

О слове "запасный"ответ Грамоты: 
http://gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_140